# how to .animate() image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have an image that rotates for ever on the screen:

####### HTML

```
<div class="WideContainerMainShow">
   <div class="ShowStrip"></div>
</div>
```

####### HTML

####### CSS

```
.WideContainerMainShow
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.ShowStrip
{
    background-image:url("someimage.png");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:10000000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    right:-550px;
}
```

####### CSS

####### Jquery onload page

```
$("div .ShowStrip").animate({ 'right': -10000000 }, 300000000);
```

####### Jquery

Comment: What is the problem that you having?

Answer (score 3):

Check this plugin about [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples)

Answer (score 0):

Call your animate recursively:

```
function rotateForever() {
  $("div .ShowStrip").animate({ ... }, 'slow', rotateForever);
}
```

In your onload, call `rotateForever()`

Comment: can you provide your latest code?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code.Instead of image i have used the text.Hope it helps
http://jsfiddle.net/WRKHk/3/